# Why am I getting this error for JavaScript Date object?

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code in JS

```js
var d = new Date(2019, 9, 14);

var currentTime = d.getTime();
var daysToAdd = 3;

var secondsInDay = 86400;

var d = new Date(currentTime + daysToAdd*secondsInDay);

var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = ("0" + (d.getMonth())).slice(-2);
var day = ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2);

console.log('result in Y-M-D is: ' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
```

This outputs to **result in Y-M-D is: 2019-09-14**

What am I doing wrong here? How to I change this to output **result in Y-M-D is: 2019-09-17** , which I originally intended to do

Comment: you need to add milliseconds.... `daysToAdd*secondsInDay*1000` Check the details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: One other issue you will come up against ... you're setting `new Date(2019, 9, 14)` - this, as you know is actually, 14th **October** 2019 - however, the output string you want to create is `2019-09-17` - which would imply 17th **September** 2019 - perhaps not what you intended

Comment: Yes sorry that was a silly mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because on this code

```
new Date(currentTime + daysToAdd*secondsInDay);
```

secondsInDay is a representation in seconds, and currentTime is represented in ms. If you multiply your secondsInDay by 1000 (to get the equivalent value in ms) you will get the desired date.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
var d = new Date(currentTime + daysToAdd*secondsInDay);
```

you can use

```
d.setDate(new Date().getDate()+3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre problem is that the constructor of the date object uses **MILISECONDS** to calculate the date, and you're using **SECONDS** to add that 3 extra days. Instead of 86400 (seconds) you need to use the value 86400000 (miliseconds).

Goodbye!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the number of days directly to `d.getDate()`

```js
var d = new Date(2019, 9, 14);
  var daysToAdd = 3;
  var new_day = d.getDate() + daysToAdd;
  var new_d = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d. getMonth(), new_day);

  alert('result in Y-M-D is: ' + new_d.getFullYear() + '-' + new_d. getMonth() + '-' + new_day);
```